# Firestore keeps disconnected when restarting internet

Tags: android, crash, google-cloud-firestore

Everytime I restart my internet firebase firestore seems to keep being disconnected and crashes when calling firestore functions. How can I properly reconnect firestore to my app? Thats's the error I'm getting(internet connection reenabled):

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces this error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code... It works perfectly fine when internet is enabled but when i turn internet off and then on again it starts crashing

Comment: There is a reason I've asked you to add the code.